# 'function' object has no attribute binary-tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

I'm trying to print a binary tree, my implementation is as following

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.l = None
        self.r = None
        self.v = val

    def get_right_child(self):
        return self.r

    def get_left_child(self):
        return self.l

    def __str__(self):
        return self.v.__str__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.v.__str__()


class Binary_tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def get_root(self):
        return self.root

    def set_root(self, val):
        self.root=Node(val)

    def is_empty(self):
        if self.root==None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def add(self, val):
        if(self.root == None):
            self.root = Node(val)
        else:
            self._add(val, self.root)

    def _add(self, val, node):
        if(val < node.v):
            if(node.l != None):
                self._add(val, node.l)
            else:
                node.l = Node(val)

        else:
            if(node.r != None):
                self._add(val, node.r)
            else:
                node.r = Node(val)

    def find(self, val):
        if(self.root != None):
            return self._find(val, self.root)
        else:
            return None

    def _find(self, val, node):
        if(val == node.v):
            return node
        elif(val < node.v and node.l != None):
            self._find(val, node.l)
        elif(val > node.v and node.r != None):
            self._find(val, node.r)




    def to_string(self):
        return self.to_string_tree(self.root, 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.to_string_tree2(self.get_root,0)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.to_string_tree2(self.get_root,0)

    def to_string_tree2(self, node, indent):

        def is_leaf(node):

            if(node.get_right_child()==None and node.get_left_child()==None):
                return True
            else:
                return False

        indentation=""
        result=""
        i=0
        if(node!=None):
           i=0

           while(i<indent):
               indentation=indentation+(" ")
               i=i+1
           if(is_leaf(node)):
               result=result+"["+node.v+"]"+"\n"
           else:
               result=result+"("+node.v+")"+"\n"
               if(node.l!=None):
                   result=result+indentation+"Izq.: "+self.to_string_tree2(node.l,indent+2)
               if(node.r!=None):
                   result=result+indentation+"Der.: "+self.to_string_tree2(node.r,indent+2)

        return result
```

this is the code I run as an example

```
a1=Binary_tree()

a1.add(7)
a1.add(3)
a1.add(10)
a1.add(11)
a1.add(9)


print(a1)
```

the error 
and I'm getting this error:

```
if(node.get_right_child()==None and node.get_left_child()==None):

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_right_child'
```

I don't get why I'm getting that error, the compiler also doesn't recognize node as a "node" (when I place the dot no functions are recommended other than the default ones for every object)

Comment: You are passing `self.get_root` as the argument to `to_string_tree2`, rather than `self.root` or `self.get_root()`.

Comment: Typically, one does not bother with such trivial getters in Python.

Comment: aaaah, "group projects" I didn't realize that, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class `Binary_tree` you implement a `__str__` and `__repr__` function by calling `self.to_string_tree2(...)`. But you do this with `self.get_root`. Note that you forgot to *call* the function. You thus should add brackets. By using `self.get_root` itself, you pass a reference to the method as parameter to the function call.

You thus can fix this with:

```
class Binary_tree:

    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return self.to_string_tree2(self.get_root(),0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.to_string_tree2(self.get_root(),0)
```